# Where does ice get the energy to lift sand adhered to its base as it melts?

Tags: energy-conservation, states-of-matter

Consider the following clip of ice melting on sand:

[image]

I'm intrigued by the fact that the sand below the ice *lifts* as the ice melts and the base of each cube lifts from the surface. Where does the energy come from to do this? Since the lifting comes from the deformation of the ice as it melts, my first vague guess is that the stress of the weight of the adhered sand somehow slightly increases the enthalpy of fusion, so the resulting air is slightly cooler than the same volume of ice melting without lifting the surface. In other words, I can only imagine that the energy comes from heat in the air, though admittedly I can't substantiate any specific mechanism much.

<sup>The clip above comes from the first 2 seconds of the music video for JOYRYDE's "DAMN", which sourced much of the footage from Macro Room.</sup>

Comment: The center of mass of the water drop is lowered by more than the sand rises - so no energy problem.  The mechanism is surface tension

Comment: @MartinBeckett I don't quite follow how the gravitational potential of the ice contributes to lifting the sand, would you mind elaborating? I can see some of the logic of surface tension to the point that it adheres the sand grains to the ice block in the first place, but have trouble seeing how it supplies or transfers energy.

Comment: Wow, Nice question... +1

Answer (score 1):

When the ice melts, a thin layer of water forms on the surface which holds the sand particles due to surface tension. The change in shape causes the sand particle to rise. Here surface tension does work to keep the sand particles adhered to the water surface.

Comment: What I'm interested in is that driving energy for the change in shape. Where does the extra work come from to lift the sand? Would the ice deform differently if it weren't lifting sand, and what would make that process more energy efficient if so?

Comment: Why does a correct answer get a negative appreciation?

Comment: The change in shape is determined by the fact that the melt water disappears in the sand layer.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and thanks for the very nice images. It would require extra work to *not* lift the sand. The reason is that sand grains adhere to the water surface . Water molecules have a dipole moment. The sand grains get polarised and stick to the water surface. This lowers the total energy cost of creating the surface and it would take energy to take the grains off. For small enough sand grains this overcomes the cost in gravitational energy. Of course the source of the melting energy is the environmental heat bath.

Comment: I guess, phrased another way, suppose the weight of the sand on the bottom of the ice is arbitrary [ignoring the ultimate strength of the ice]. What variables are involved towards the height the sand gets lifted? Is ambient temperature a factor (e.g. as a heat engine)? Or perhaps the amount of gravitational potential of the ice block?